# How to open a named pipe from VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a C++ application that can take commands through a named pipe. Is it any way to open a named pipe from vbscript and send a text string, for example "restart" through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work if you open `\\.\pipe\YourPipeName`? The `\\.\` notation gets you up one more level in the Windows namespace compared to the ordinary file system, from there you can access the pipes etc. I have no idea though if it works from VBScript.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(VS.85).aspx#win32_device_namespaces) has some information on the file vs. Win32 namespaces.

CodeSegment has a [sample](http://www.codesegment.com/sms_studio_help/Help/Tutorial/Samples/How%20to%20Send%20a%20Message%20through%20Named%20Pipe.htm) on writing to named pipes from VbScript.

Comment: I need to open it using FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile, or something else?

Comment: Try with `FileSystemOjbect.OpenTextFile`, if it supports named pipes it should work.

Comment: The CodeSegment link seems broken.