# Send variables to windows service?

Tags: service, vbscript, active-directory

I'm starting to write a Windows Service that's supposed to update Active Directory with user information that is sent from a third party application. The question is, how should the service read the values to update? I mean, the third party application has an event handler built in where I can run a vbscript. In this vbscript I can pick up the values I want to update AD with, but what's the best way of doing this?

I was thinking of storing the variables in a file that the windows service reads. But which format would be the best to use? XML? INI? Simple text file? Also, the windows service should be notified that there is a job for it to do. How does one do that with services? Add a timer that checks if there is anything to do? Or is it possible to actually connect to the service via vbscript?

Answer (score 1):

In general a file is not the best interface for doing [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Better ways would be [named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2673264/1630171) or TCP sockets. To be able to use the latter in VBScript you'd need an additional component, though, e.g. [this](http://www.activexperts.com/network-component/) or [this](http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/socket_connect.asp).

Comment: Wow, it just got a lot more complicated than using vbscripts! Should have thought somebody else have already created a service that allows me to connect to it using named pipes and vbscript and then connect to Active Directory?