# How to pass a value from Visual Basic 6 program to VBscript code?

Tags: vbscript, vb6

I have a VB6 code and another VBScript which runs in the background. I need to pass a variable periodically (say, with a timer) from VB6 code to the background VBscript. Is there any way other than write down to temporary file and read it from VBscript?

Tuncay, Thanks...

Comment: You can use command line arguments while calling vbs file. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee156618.aspx

Comment: Right. But my VBscript will work once and do some background processes. During this period, I need to pass a value continuously to running vbscript.

Comment: In that case, using a file is a good option. The other options that you can use are using clipboard or a database.

Comment: You can use custom environment variable as well if you are just using a variable's data. I am not sure how do you work with EVs in VB6 but its easy to implement in VB.NET.

Comment: Using clipboard seems practical. Let me try this, thanks!

Comment: Windows® Script Components provide you with an easy way to create powerful, reusable COM components in script. You create script components using any scripting language that supports the Microsoft® ActiveX® Scripting interfaces. Script languages that support these interfaces include JScript, Microsoft® Visual Basic® Scripting Edition (VBScript), PERLScript, PScript, and Python.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233148(v=vs.60).asp

Comment: msdn link doesn't work...

Comment: Clipboard works very well, but I don't guess its side effects. Let's see. But this method passes only one value. When I need several parameters clipboard has no mean.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa233148(v=vs.60).aspx this is the link from the page. When I click prev link it doesn't work but even though it seems identical.

Comment: So you have this long running VBScript batch that a VB6 app needs to interrupt and pass some values in or the other way -- the batch polls periodically (1 sec) if there is a VB6 app started and gets config values from app's current instance?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Message Queues, which are accessible from both VB6 and VBS. They're designed for this purpose. If the following link rots, search for [VBS and MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Another possibility is named (or anonymous) pipes as described in a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673248/how-to-open-a-named-pipe-from-vbscript).

Comment: Thanks but currently it is hard to understand for me. I will try it.

Comment: The sample from the link bombs w/ `ActiveX component can't create object: 'MSMQ.MSMQQueueInfo'`. You don't suggest to install `Message Queuing Server` just to pass a string from VBScript?

Comment: @wqw - MSMQ is a stock (but optional) Windows component. It's easy to include it if it's not in your current setup, but you're right that not everyone will want to. In that case ***pipes*** are just as effective and guaranteed to be available.